# Operation failed, QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID failed due to Library not registered

Tags: c#, excel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace GridComplete
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static Excel.Workbook MyBook;
        private static Excel.Application MyApp;
        private static Excel.Worksheet MySheet;

        private void bRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyApp = new Excel.Application();
            MyApp.Visible = false;
            MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(tbFile1);
            MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1];

        }

    }
}
```

On the line that sets MyApp.Visible to false, I get the following unhandled exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in GridComplete.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).

** I can't seem to figure what's going on.  I tried to delete keys from the registry and rerun.  That didn't work.  I also fully uninstalled Microsoft Office, then reinstalled.  I'm not sure what else to do to fix this issue.

Comment: The registry on your machine is missing the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} key.  Reinstalling Office certainly ought to fix that, very unhealthy of course.  Get another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you don't have specified version of Microsoft Excel installed on computer where you running that code. Or it's installation broken. Try to re-install Office

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the incorrect vesion information in registry. I once installed the Office 365, and later I uninstall it, and install the Offic 2010. So there are two items there,but only one can work.

Firstly you can open `registry editor`, please **must** do the backup by `File -> Export -> Check Export range to All`.

Secondly, you can check the item `{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` by `Ctrl + F`, select it and get the value of `TypeLib`, remember the value. To my computer, it is 1.7, I guess it is for Office 2010, the current installed Office.

Then into HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib, and select item `{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` and extend, I have two subitem, one is 1.7, the other is an empty 1.9. After I delete 1.9, the program works.

[Related information in Chinese](https://answers.microsoft.com/zh-hans/windows/forum/all/%E6%8A%A5%E9%94%99%E4%BF%A1%E6%81%AF/5281f50d-25f2-4eb0-91ad-2bd97cf0f762)

Answer (score 0):

('_Application cannot be converted' .... 'TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED')

After a messy uninstallation and reinstallation of an older version of Office. I solved it by following the advice of another forum thread, which unfortunately I can't find here. Basically, I searched the registry for the CLSID in the error message {00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}.

It was found in 3-4 places, but the important one was here:
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

[image]

I deleted the higher one, and the problem was solved for me.